# Query registry based on value inside key without knowing key name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry, key, uninstallation

I am a system administrator at a high school and I would like to uninstall LanSchool off all my teachers laptops, however the uninstall requires that it be uninstalled using the MSI that installed it, this I have found can be circumvented by uninstalling using the UninstallString found in the registry HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows(SID) UninstallString=Value

The issue I am having however is the SID is a variable for different versions of the software.

Inside the variable key however, is the DisplayName "LanSchool Teacher".

I would like to know if it is possible to somehow REG QUERY the DisplayName, then from there export the KEY to a txt file to Set it as a variable in CMD and then run an msiexec.exe /X{SIDVariable} /quiet

This would then uninstall LanSchool Teacher from that computer.

My question is: How do I REG QUERY without knowing the KEY Name as it would vary per teachers laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, it looks to me that you could use

```
REG Query HKLM\Software\Microsoft /V "DisplayName" /S
```

and then parse the output to find the name of the key you are looking for. `/V` indicates to query for a value.`/S` indicates the search should be done recursively.

If this does not work and/or if I did not understand your question, check out [Rob van der Woude's Scripting Pages](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regsearch.php) which have a fairly extensive overview about searching the registry. This might teach you other ways to find your key as well.

Comment: I currently have reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Wow6432Node\Windows\Uninstall" /v "DisplayName" /s > %temp%\lanschool.txt however this doesn't work for me and gives me a Error: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

Comment: The path to search would be `HKLM\Software\Microsoft` since the `Windows` part has an unknown suffix (which you omitted)

Comment: Actually I tried REG QUERY "HKLM\Software" /v "DisplayName" /s > %temp%\lanschool.txt and this worked for me, however now I have a text file full of DisplayNames....how can I now find the KeyName to store as a variable? @Reinier

Comment: Above the value of the `DisplayName`, the key itself should be outputted. If you have multiple (undesired) `DisplayName` values then you could try to use the `/D` flag instead of `/V` and search for `"LanSchool Teacher"`. That will take longer though.

Comment: Actually I tried using /F and that gave me what I wanted, however now I have the information how would I then pull that information. At the moment it has output the key and the display name, I need to get the KeyName (Currently an SID) from the end of the Reg Key.